# Chart doesn't show up on mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, charts

I am using PhoneGap to build a mobile app and one of the pages needs to display a chart and I am using Chart.js. I am using the following code but the chart doesn't appear and gives me an empty display for the page. The alert shows when I go to my chart page.

Is there any issues with displaying charts for PhoneGap applications for chart.js?

index.html

```
<article>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</article>

<script src="js/Charts/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chartScript.js"></script>
```

chartScript.js

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#chart", function () {
    alert("Able to enter");

    var pieData = [
       {
           value: 25,
           label: 'Java',
           labelColor: 'black',
           color: '#811BD6'
       },
       {
           value: 10,
           label: 'Scala',
           color: '#9CBABA'
       },
       {
           value: 30,
           label: 'PHP',
           color: '#D18177'
       },
       {
           value: 35,
           label: 'HTML',
           color: '#6AE128'
       }
    ];

    var context = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(pieData);

});
```

Comment: I'd also alert `able to exit`. I wrote few apps on cordova, I was using jshybugger and it helped me a lot, but it's not free, you may consider that though.

Comment: @MaciejKwas Able to Alert Exit too.

Comment: You must draw chart when html element is visible.